# Parsing Through Nested Dictionary to Create Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, parsing

I've got the following list which contains nested dictionaries:

```
    [{'metrics': {'sales': '10', 'revenue': '75'}, 'dimensions': {'date': '2021-07-25 
    00:00:00', 'geo': ‘california’}},
    {'metrics': {'sales': '5', 'revenue': '40'}, 'dimensions': {'date': '2021-07-25 00:00:00', 
    'geo': ‘texas’}}]
```

I want to convert it into one dataframe but need to parse through both "metrics" and "dimensions" keys.

Desired output:

```
    date            geo         sales   revenue
    7/25/2021 0:00  california  10      75
    7/25/2021 0:00  texas       5       40
```

Code I'm running:

```
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(list['metrics']['dimensions']))
```

Output:

```
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How do I get the desired output?

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(your_list)`

Comment: works perfect. thanks!